# Connecting a web APP using LINQ to a database and passing values to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

For a while i have been googling how to use LINQ and connecting my stored procedures in c#. Anyone out there can give me some form of hint or some sort of help? That would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the Visual Studio / DBML designer scaffold the stored procedure for you and generate the required code to call it, with strongly typed parameters. Just drag the required stored procedure within the DBML designer:

- dragging it within an existing entity will make your stored procedure returns a collection of instances of that type, if possible;
- dragging it to the *Stored procedures* panel will make it returns a collection of rows specific to that stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use a Linq-to-Sql layer or .dbml.  Scott Guthrie has a great series of blog posts on setting this up.  Start here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx